# What cron job is /usr/lib/sa/sa1

Tags: centos, cron

I have logwatch enabled for my machine. Suddenly I see this line in my logwatch

```
/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1 : 4297 times
/usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A : 29 times
run-part /etc/cron.hourly : 716
```

I tried crontab -e but I dont see any entries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is configured in `/etc/cron.d/sysstat`.

And what it is (quote `man sa1`):

```
sa1  -  Collect and store binary data in the system activity daily data file.
```

And (`man sa2`):

```
sa2 - Write a daily report in the /var/log/sa directory.
```

Comment: How is it enabled by default is it? I have other machines same but dont have this cron in them ?

Comment: @biz14 it is part of the `sysstat` package, hosts which have this package installed have this cronjob (See: `rpm -qf /etc/cron.d/sysstat`)

Comment: @What surprise me I install all 3 machines with same centos 6.4 machine only this one having it I know that I did not installed it by myself else I am sure I am aware of it ? Could be any hacking into the machine ?

Comment: @biz14 well, everything is possible I suppose. But I'd check `/var/log/yum.log` first to see if it was installed as a dependency.

Comment: @Yes I am looking through my yum.log what to look for what is the name of this dependency?

Comment: I saw this in the log May 09 02:07:21 Installed: 1:dmidecode-2.11-2.el6.x86_64
May 12 12:06:43 Installed: sysstat-9.0.4-20.el6.x86_64 but why is this installed ?

Comment: I'd add here that `sa1` makes "snapshots" (usually) every 10 mins, and `sa2` transforms them into 1 daily report. It took me some time to figure it out. And generally, the connection between `sa1`, `sa2`, `sar`, `sadc`. What is front end to what. And what do the names even mean?.. I guess "r" means "report." :)